# Bash variable escaping in a Jenkinsfile

Tags: bash, curl, github, jenkins

I am trying the following:

```
sh '''
    changelog=$(git log `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD^`..HEAD --oneline)
    curl --data '{"\tag_name\": \\"v0.0.${BUILD_NUMBER}\\",\"target_commitish\": \"master\",\"name\": \\"Release v0.0.$BUILD_NUMBER\\",\"body\": \\"$changelog\\",\"draft\": false,\"prerelease\": false}' https://****/api/v3/repos/****/****/releases?access_token=$JENKINS_ACCESS_TOKEN_PSW
'''
```

Basically I want to include "dynamic" values for `tag`, `name` and `body` which are taken using the Jenkins build number (`$BUILD_NUMBER`) and a bash variable containing the result of `git log` (`changelog`).

I've made all sort of single and double quotes and other escaping changes that I am not sure anymore how it should be.

This currently fails with:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: variable
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: escaping
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 9a21d71
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: more
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: escaping
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: attempts
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 708ed0f
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: more
>   curl: (6) Could not resolve host: escaping'

It can't handle the contents inside the `changelog` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge here is not just to properly escape the quotes when dynamically generating a string, but also to ensure that the result is a valid JSON. For example in your case `changelog` may contain newlines and quotes and, when it is expanded into the `"body": "$changelog"` part of your POST data, those characters must be properly escaped.

To this end use the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) utility to generate the POST JSON data as explained in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411136/6394138) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410686/how-can-i-post-a-json-string-with-curl-that-has-characters-that-need-escaping):

```
sh '''
    changelog=$(git log `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD^`..HEAD --oneline)
    jq -n --arg tagname "v0.0.$BUILD_NUMBER"      \
          --arg name "Release v0.0.$BUILD_NUMBER" \
          --arg body "$changelog"                 \
          '{"tag_name": $tagname, "target_commitish": "master", "name": $name, "body": $body, "draft": false, "prerelease": false}'  |
    curl -d@- https://****/api/v3/repos/****/****/releases?access_token=$JENKINS_ACCESS_TOKEN_PSW
'''
```

Comment: Hmm... this isn't working well for me, it fails with "Problems parsing JSON".  See result from Jenkins here: https://pastebin.com/kSVd57Zc

Comment: @IdanAdar What exactly is not working? I have hard time guessing it from the provided data.

Comment: Well, it fails due parsing the JSON, that's the only result I get. The pastebin shows the command that is executed.

Comment: The only problem that I can see is that the contents of `body` includes an unescaped newline. Please try this command directly and tell me if it works: `curl --data '{"tag_name": "v0.0.39", "target_commitish": "master", "name": "Release v0.0.39", "body": "b8898d1 add missing quotes\nbe0ab22 attempt with curldata", "draft": false, "prerelease": false}' 'https://****/api/v3/repos/****/****/releases?access_token=****'`

Comment: Then, since `changelog` can contain newline characters they must be replaced with escape sequences. I will update the answer shortly.

Comment: Is the `jq` tool (for generating valid JSONs) available in your environment?

Comment: It can be available, yeah.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help @Leon!